# Updating files when deployed (Django/Python)

Tags: django, git, vim, deployment

I am trying to update files on a project that already has been deployed. The changes are not taking place when seeing it deployed, though when I sudo vim these files via GitBash, it shows the changes. Here's how I did when I'm logged into the server Ubuntu via AWS.

```
cd into the project
git add .
git commit -a -m "message"
git pull origin master
```

(it comes out a Nano screen--so I input a message then Ctrl X and then respond "no") and it shows the changes through vim.

There's no changes when I refresh the deployed project, and not even when I reboot it via AWS. Can someone please share the steps to make changes and show changes on a deployed project? Thank you so much, I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the service running your app to update the app:

```
sudo systemctl restart service_name
```